# R regex can replace opening bracket but not closing bracket

Tags: r, regex, gsub, brackets, square-bracket

I am trying to replace opening and closing brackets in a string. R seems to do it for the opening bracket:

```
> gsub("[\\[]","==","hello [world]")
[1] "hello ==world]"
```

but not for the closing brackets

```
> gsub("[\\]]","==","hello [world]")
[1] "hello [world]"
```

Why is this so?

Comment: As far as  I understood, the question is about using a `[` and `]` inside a bracket expression/character class, right? There are other answers dwelling on something else, thus, it could be a good idea to adjust the question title and question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, the pattern in `gsub("[\\]]","==","hello\\] [world]")`, `[\]]`, is effectively matching a `\` followed with `]`. Try `gsub("[\\]]","==","hello\\] [world]")`, and the result will be `hello== [world]`, the literal backslash will get replaced.

**In a TRE regex pattern, a `\` inside a bracket expression matches a literal backslash.**

As a fix for your `"[\\]]"` regex, you may remove the `\` from the pattern:

```
gsub("[[]","==","hello [world]")
```

See [this R online demo](https://ideone.com/U1GqJ4).

You may escape it in a PCRE pattern though, as PCRE *character classes* allow escaped characters inside them:

```
gsub("[\\[]","==","hello [world]", perl=TRUE)
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/KLtAcc)

If you need to replace either `[` or `]`, just put the `][` inside the bracket expression:

```
 gsub("[][]","==","hello [world]")
```

Comment: Thanks. To do both, `gsub("[\\[]]","==","Hello [World]"` doesn't work but `gsub("[]\\[]","==","Hello [World]")`  does. Is there a rhyme or reason for this?

Comment: FYI: The `]` inside a `[...]` is treated as a literal `]` when it is placed after the open `[`, thus, the `[][]` effectively matches a literal `[` or a literal `]`.

Comment: In a TRE regex, a backslash inside a bracket expression is treated as a literal backslash. In your `"[]\\[]"`, you match either `]`, or ``\`` or `[`. See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/8C8mV0) where `gsub("[]\\[]","==", "Hello \\ [World]")` replaces 3 chars in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

This simply works:

```
gsub("]", "==","hello [world]")
#"hello [world=="
```

Answer (score 1):

A maybe more readable/straight forward way to do it is with `stringi`,

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_regex('hello [world]', '\\[|]', '==')
#[1] "hello ==world=="
```